# How to handle authentication logout from hangfire dashboard?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I wanted to have a logout where after i click the back it will display the login form again in hangfire dashboard, currently I only have swagger page and hangfire dashboard.

My code in startup below

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true,
                AppPath =  "https://localhost:7179/swagger/index.html",
                DashboardTitle = "My Website",
                Authorization = new[]

        {
                new HangfireBasicAuthenticationFilter.HangfireCustomBasicAuthenticationFilter{
                    User = "user",
                    Pass = "passs"
                }
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have implemented the authentication and authorization before configuring `Hangfire` and securing it with a login page.

In your `Program.cs`, before calling `app.UseHangfireDashboard()`, add this

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

***Make sure your authentication and authorization work properly before continuing.***

---

Now call `app.UseHangfireDashboard()` and configure it like so

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    // class that will handle authorization access to Hangfire page
    Authorization = new[] { new HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter() },

    // url pathname that will be redirected to on button click
    AppPath = "/login",

    IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true
});
```

In `HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter`, set authorization access to `Hangfire` page based on a role.
[Check this other example from the docs.](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#configuring-authorization)

```
public class HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext dashboardContext)
    {
        // get the context
        HttpContext? httpContext = dashboardContext.GetHttpContext();

        if (httpContext is null
            || httpContext.User.Identity is not ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity
            || claimsIdentity.Claims is null
            || !claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
            return false; // refuse access if no Claims is set

        // get list of claims
        IEnumerable<Claim> listUserClaims = claimsIdentity.Claims ?? Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

        // grant access if user has specific role in their claims
        // ex: if 'specificRole' is found in roles, grant access, else refuse
        return listUserClaims
               .Where(role => role.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
               .Select(s => s?.Value?.Trim() ?? string.Empty)
               .Contains("specificRole");
    }
}
```

Finally, in you login page controller, check if context exist and user has some roles.

If the context is null or roles are empty, then return your login page, else your user is already logged in and just redirect them to home page

Comment: Thank you for replying with my question , but currently I haven't setup Identity which means also that i don't have user management , What i have is just hangfire dashboard which authorization is hardcoded in it. So my problem is how im gonna sign out or clear that details after i login and can relogin again.

Comment: @ChoyRoman then you should setup a proper way to authenticate your users, restrict their access and remove the authorization token when the back button is clicked.

Comment: Yes I have an idea of removing that authorization token once back button is clicked, but I cant trace where to remove it. Please if you have reference of it share it with us . thank you